# XPath search in Multiple Values

Tags: xml, search, xpath

I have a XML like:

```
<user id="1">
  <first_name>Max</first_name>
  <last_name>Mustermann</last_name>
</user>
```

How can I create the XPath to get the user_id when I search "Max Mustermann"

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If that example XML is accurate, *including the indentation* (i.e. there is a whitespace-only text node in between the closing `</first_name>` and opening `<last_name>` tags), then you can simply use `normalize-space()`:

```
//user[normalize-space() = 'Max Mustermann']/@id
```

This works because the string value of an element node in XPath is by definition the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes, and applying `normalize-space` to that value will strip off the leading and trailing whitespace and collapse any internal runs of whitespace characters down to a single space.

If the XML doesn't contain those whitespace text nodes then the `user` element's `normalize-space()` value would be `MaxMustermann`, so you'll have to construct the value for comparison by hand:

```
//user[normalize-space(concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)) = 'Max Mustermann']/@id
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this...?

```
//user[first_name='Max' and last_name='Mustermann']/@id
```

Comment: I deleted my answer, i opened other tab to test my expression and you posted at this moment :)

Comment: I suspect the OP will need a `//` rather than just a `/` at the start - this expression is correct if the OP's input is the complete XML document but then there's no need to "search" for anything if the input only contains one `user`...

Comment: That's a fair comment @Ian... updated - thanks.  And I do like your solution - very clever, and something I would have never considered